# Write a password protected tar.gz file in Java

Tags: java

I know I can use [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/) to create tar.gz file

But I can't find how to set a password to the tar file.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good practice is to use GPG - https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/book1.html

Once your tar.gz is created you can than encrypt it. GPG is quite more secure than just adding a password protection.

You may choose to use a java library https://www.gnupg.org/related_software/libraries.html
or you can just execute shell commands from your app to encrypt your .tar.gz and remove the not encrypted.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.